# use of callable in php

Tags: php, callable

I am trying to mimic php's inbuilt usort function definition in my implementation below:

```
class heapSort {
    static function hsort(array &$array, callable $cmp_function){
       // logic
    }
}

class utility{
    static function mycomparator(){
        // logic
    }
}

$array = array(5,3,8,1);
$callback = array('utility','mycomparator');
heapSort::hsort($array, $callback);
```

While the variable `$callback` is "callable" why do I get below fatal error?

> Argument 2 passed to heapSort::hsort() must be an instance of callable.

More specifically, how do I make/typecast a `$variable` to callable?

Comment: `callable` isn't an actual type until 5.4, see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for more info, but your code seems to be correct. What version of PHP is this?

Comment: because your callback is not a valid one , try "utility::mycomparator" .instead of an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`callable` is only supported `PHP 5.4` try using `is_callable` instead

```
static function hsort(array &$array, $cmp_function) {
    if (! is_callable($cmp_function))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Function not callable");
}
```

Comment: After my own testing I was about to post this same code. If you change the original code from `callable $cmp_function` to `potato $cmp_function` you will get the error: `Argument 2 passed to heapSort::hsort() must be an instance of potato`.

Comment: The OP wants callable .. you got the error because `potato` did not implement `__invoke` see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke

Comment: the point of the potato example is to illustrate that the problem is not that the argument was not of the correct type, but that the type OP is declaring does not exist in his version and the error will simply reference any fake type you put in.